# Schedule posts on Facebook page with PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to schedule wall posts to be added to the Facebook business page in the future.

As far as I can see Facebook does not recommend to use "offline_access" anymore.

How would you do that?

This is my code so far. It works if I am already logged into Facebook.

**EDIT:** Naturally I will create some code that check the schedule that I pull from the database. And use a cron job to regulary check that schedule.

```
require_once('src/facebook.php');

$config = array(
    'appId'  => 'xxxxxxx',
    'secret' => 'xxxxxxx',
);

$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$user_id = $facebook->getUser();

$page_info = $facebook->api("/PAGE_ID?fields=access_token");

try {
    $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/PAGE_ID/feed', 'POST',
    array (
        'link' => 'http://www.example.com/',
        'message' => 'This is a test',
        'access_token'  => $page_info['access_token']
    ));
} catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array(
        'scope' => 'publish_stream'
    ));

    print_r($e->getType());
    print_r($e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: So you want to post this e.g. every 1 hour?

Comment: This is just an example. I will pull message txt from the database and once a day I will check if any posts needs to be published. Above code is all about how you make sure Facebook does expire the access token.

Comment: So you could make a cronjob which runs this every day.

Comment: Yes, but the questions was in regards to the access_token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to extend access_token periodically now. All other code should be working fine as previously